# Atmosphere never uses weboscket with Jboss 7

Tags: websocket, long-polling, atmosphere

I would like to run some example with Atmosphere using WebSocket with Jboss 7.

I tried a lot of examples of this page https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/samples and others.

I tried with JBoss 7.1.1.Final, 7.1.3.Final and Jboss EAP 6.1(JBoss AS 7.2).

I followed these instructions https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-JBoss-WebSocket-Support

I tried with different versions of Atmosphere, so I do not know what else to do, I always get **Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending** on firebug

Please can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that your browser is compatible with websocket.

Comment: Yes, I am using the last version of firefox and chorme for linux. Thhese same projects works well using websockets with tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Check this list:

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers

JBoss 5, 6, 7 is not compatible with websocket.

You can try jetty 7+, I run atmosphere in jetty 8 very well.

Comment: But according to this article, its possible to run websockets with Jboss
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-JBoss-WebSocket-Support